# Why is it "your Majesty", but "my Lord"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, honorifics

Why is it "your Majesty", but "my Lord"?

Comment: Note that it's also "your Grace" (Duke/archbishop), "your Honour" (judge), "your Excellency" (ambassador), "your Holiness" (pope), "your Eminence" (cardinal) - only Lord is "my", though it's often qualified ("my Lord Bishop", for example)

Comment: @RichardGadsden "Your lordship" can also be used for lords.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, some etymology. I'll try to keep it short.

*Lord* has deep Germanic roots. Etymonline [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=lord&searchmode=none):

> **lord**
>   M.E. *laverd*, *loverd* (13c.), from O.E. *hlaford* "master of a household, ruler, superior," also "God" (translating L. *Dominus*, though O.E. *drihten* was used more often), earlier *hlafweard*, lit. "one who guards the loaves," from *hlaf* "bread, loaf" + *weard* "keeper, guardian, ward."

*Majesty* was borrowed, ultimately from Latin and together with its meaning. Etymonline [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=majesty&searchmode=none):

> **majesty**
>  
>   c.1300, "greatness, glory," from O.Fr. *majeste* "grandeur, nobility," from L. *majestatem* (nom. *majestas*) "greatness, dignity, honor, excellence," from stem of *major* (neut. *majus*), comp. of *magnus* "great." Earliest Eng. sense is of God, reference to kings and queens (late 14c.) is from Romance languages and descends from the Roman Empire.

Wikipedia [adds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majesty#Origin):

> Originally, during the Roman republic, the word *maiestas* was the legal term for the supreme status and dignity of the state, to be respected above everything else. [...] It was first assumed by Charles V, Holy Roman Emperor, who believed that, as an emperor, 
>   he deserved a style greater than Highness, which had been used by preceding emperors and 
>   kings. Soon, King Francis I of France and King Henry VIII of England followed his example.

What I take from all this is:

1. The word *lord*, originally and all throughout its history, referred to some*one*, a person (or a personification of God, as opposed to God as an abstract concept). It's only natural to refer to my guardian, my ruler and my master as, well, *my* guardian, ruler and master rather than *your*, *his* or *her* guardian, ruler and master.
2. The word *majesty*, on the other hand, always referred to some*thing*, a concept, 
   a trait that was attributed *to* someone — much like *highness*, *honor*, and *excellence*. When I am talking about a king (or a judge), I attribute majesty (or honor) to him rather than to myself.

Answer (score 33):

Very succinctly, majesty, grace, honor, and royal highness are *qualities* of the exalted person being addressed, while lord, liege, and king are titles describing the superior relationship of the one addressed (superior to me, that is).

Comment: This is the best answer by far. Here's hoping it'll eventually get voted above the others...

Comment: Yes. That is why in the High Court (and above) in England we address the judges as "my Lord" but refer to them as "your Lordship" - the second is a quality they possess rather than a reference to themselves. Example "My Lord, has your Lordship read the agreed trial bundle?"

Comment: @Francis Davey Excellent observation

Answer (score 2):

I would venture that lord is a title while Majesty comes from the adjective majestic. So "your majesty" means "you who are majestic", while "my lord" means "the lord of me".

Comment: I completely agree with the sentiment, but completely disagree with the etymology. The adjective *majestic* was derived from the much older noun *majesty* around 1600, not the other way round.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: But Majesty must surely be a derived adjective, having a +y suffix. Perhaps from the Latin "magister"?

Answer (score 1):

Explaining "my lord" is easy, "my lord" is the person who is the lord of me. "Your lord" would be the person who is the lord of you rather than me.

The function of the possessive (your, her, his) in "your majesty" or "her majesty" or "his royal highness" seems to be to indicate that the noun indicates a person, but this is some kind of archaic or rare usage.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this party, but it seems to me that no-one has made the most important point:  namely that it's "my Lord", but "your Lordship" -- the point being that one refers to the individual directly ("my Lord"), and the other refers to the same individual obliquely ("your Lordship"), and is a kind of metonymy.

Comment: "my lord" is a vocative form "Will you have a drink, Bill?" cf "Will you have some whisky, my lord?"  "Your lordship" is generally used in place of a pronoun - not "As *you* wish" but "As your lordship wishes". A kind of respectful use of the third person.