# Why does "Your grace" use "Your"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I know the meaning of this expression, but I want to know how it got what it means.

When we say "**My lord**", it's really obvious what we're talking about: *somebody is my lord*. I couldn't come up with a similar argument about "**Your grace**". On a comment on another question, "Your majesty" (which might be a similar usage) was related to "*you, who are majestic*". Is that it? Is there any rule to connect the dots between such phrases and what they actually mean and how they're constructed? And how's that a title for someone; Your grace? That's strange.

Why isn't it "**The grace**"? What's the role of "Your" to make a title? How does putting "your" before "grace" make a title? Can't figure out the structure.

I'm just looking for why we use that phrase as a title or an addressing and how we got to that phrase, not the "grace" alone, but "your grace".

Comment: The same question can be raised about *your honour*, *your worship*, or *your excellency*.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, actually. Thanks.

Comment: You,who has the grace? Translated by whom and where?

Comment: @Lambie Sorry. I remembered the wrong phrase. It was "Your majesty". https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2819/73391

Comment: Please edit your question. What do you mean translated by? Please add specifics to your question.

Comment: @Lambie I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the OED:

> 8. Chiefly with capital initial. a. With a possessive adjective: a title of respect, esp. for a person of royal or noble rank. Frequently
>      (in your Grace) as a form of address. Now archaic or hist. **Formerly
>      (in England until the reign of Henry VIII and in Scotland until 1707)
>      used for a monarch or prince; now replaced by Majesty or Highness (see
>      majesty n. 2, highness n. 2b).**
>
> b. spec. **As the title given to a duke, duchess, or archbishop. (Now
>   the only non-historical use.**)

Here is a snippet from the etymology of it (which is very long) from there:
Etymology: < Anglo-Norman grase, graze, Anglo-Norman and Old French, Middle French grace, Anglo-Norman and Middle French grasse (Middle French, French grâce ) favour, benevolence, an instance or manifestation of favour, (specifically) **the benevolent influence and favour shown by God to mankind** (all end of the 11th cent.), (chiefly in plural) thanks (1135), talent, virtue (second half of the 12th cent.), (in plural) prayer of thanksgiving after a meal (c1160), pardon, mercy, forgiveness [etc. etc.]

With the idea of the divine right of kings is also the idea of **By the Grace of God**.

The only person above a king was God. And the kings were also subject to God's Grace, in that sense they were like all others. So, I suppose that historically, there came a time when this identification of the king as having God's "special" grace was turned into a form of address.

Comment: Related: [1](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/838/457), [2](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6070/38), [3](http://elies.rediris.es/elies22/cap73.htm), [4](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap09-03-pronomes_de_tratamento). *Bonne chance!* :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm not sure if I got the answer to my question. Why is it "your grace" and not something like "the grace" or "God's grace"; which are more meaningful titles and have a familiar structure?

Comment: @mrmowji Because it is too intimate to use the second person to address someone that important so directly. The style of instead addressing that elevated person's "grace" as a form of courteous address allowed for the use of more distancing third person forms. This practice developed throughout Europe around the same time and for the same reason.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks. So we're addressing somebody's grace to be able to use third-person forms. Good thing to know. That make sense I guess.

Comment: Yes, Your Grace, Your Highness, Your Majesty addresses the person's station, not the person directly. It's as if there were a cloud around the person of grace, highness or majesty, and that is what is being addressed. It all leads back to the idea of greatest used in Rome: Latin maiestas, greatness. Yes, one can provide all the languages such as Portuguese, Spanish and French, but is that really relevant **here**?

Answer (score 1):

'You who are not my peer must address my Grace rather than my person,' says the duke.  Entire books have been written detailing forms of address of this kind and they vary widely not just by the person's title, but by country.  For example, Catholic bishops in the United States are customarily addressed orally as Your Excellency, whereas Catholic bishops in Ireland are customarily addressed orally as Your Grace.  The forms vary also over time as customs change.  The structure of them is the result of the notion that the untitled, commoners, are not to address the titled familiarly, but rather to address their Highness, their Excellency or whatnot.  Think of it that way and the grammar makes sense.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which was about the use of "your Grace" instead of "my Grace" (in line with "my Lord".