# What is the grammar on Your honor/My lord?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, american-english, honorifics

Your honor, My lord, Your highness, My lady all refer to another person. What are the rules behind that?

The striked-out questions are answered by [Why is it "your Majesty", but "my Lord"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/why-is-it-your-majesty-but-my-lord) . Thank you guys!

<s>Why do we use "Your" while sometimes use "My"?</s>

<s>First, let's say, Tom is my friend. I would say "My friend, would you like a coffee?" It would be weird if I say "Your friend, would you like a coffee?"</s>

<s>Why don't we use "Your friend" like "Your honor"?</s>

Second, I feel it looks like Apposition if I interpret "Your honor" as "You, honor". Why do we use the possessive form?

Third, say I'm a loser. I would like to coin an honorable form for other people to call me. Which is more correct, "Your loser" or "My loser"?

I'm particularly interested in the usage in the United States if there's any difference.

Comment: Here is a question you should have consulted first (but as there are 631 results for the research "My Lord", it's quicker to ask someone, anyway ): https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2812/349876

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate. If it is not, please [edit] this question to explain what it is you want to know which is not answered at the other one (particularly in the highest-voted answer).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Could you check my second and third questions? For the third one, from the duplicate, since loser looks like referring to _someone_, is "My loser" more correct?

Comment: Yes. *Your* refers to an attribute of the person addressed ("Your lordship/ladyship/majesty/honour/worship"); *My* refers to the addressed person himself ("My lord/lady/liege/king/loser").

Comment: As this is a British English expression, please use the original spelling: “Your Honour”.

Comment: @David will do, Your Honour.